# How to migrate gift card account

Tags: magento2, data-migration

I have approx 2000 records in gift card account in magento1.

Now i want to migrate that records in new magento2.

is it possible to migrate in new magento2 if few products or few customers are not available in new magento2 site?

Any idea how to integrate and how many tables i need to migrate?

Answer (score 1):

If the extension is same then it may possible that table structure is same.

If it is the case then you can easily migrate your records.

If table name has changed, then you have to add rename node in your `map.xml` like below

```
<rename>
    <document>M1TableName</document>
    <to>M2TableName</to>
</rename>
```